# suggestion for tag removal

Tags: discussion

Im not sure where to ask this, or whom to address it to, so I hope this question is within site protocol.

I would like to suggest the removal of tag: carthrob.
The tag Cartthrob exists for tagging questions relating to that extension and "carthrob" seems to exist due to someone misspelling the tag.

I edited about 5 posts yesterday to remove them from carthrob and retagged as cartthrob.  As such the tag [carthrob] currently contains no posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good catch. This is exactly what tag synonyms are for.

> Incorrectly tagged questions are hard to find and answer. If you know
>   of common, alternate spellings or phrasings for this tag, add them
>   here so we can automatically correct them in the future. For example,
>   suggest “bike” as a synonym for bicycle, or “sock” for socks.

I proposed a tag synonym for this misspelling of cartthrob. You can vote for it here: https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/tags/cartthrob/synonyms

Comment: Since [tag:cartthrob] is the misspelled tag, should not [tag:carthrob] be the main tag and [tag:cartthrob] the synonym tag?